# how to find users who have a specific points and not subscribed a record in two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the users only who have more of a particular number of points and also who does not have subscribed for that particular lesson in one of my promo competition code. I am just wondering if I should include the reward points in the membership table just to make it easier? I have read somewhere that I can do this with inner join but I don't have a matching column....

````php
<?php
ob_start();
include_once __DIR__ . '/header2.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php?level3promo=notlogin'>";
    exit();
} else {
    if ($_SESSION['u_permission'] == 0) {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=nopermission'>";
        exit();
    } else {
        include_once __DIR__ . '/includes/dbh.php';

        $category = strip_tags($_POST['category']);
        $csrf = strip_tags($_POST['csrf']);


        if (!isset($_SESSION['key'])) {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=notset'>";
            exit();
        } else {

            if ($csrf !== $_SESSION['key']) {

                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=errorwithform'>";
                exit();
            } else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM level3promo WHERE id = ?;";

                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                //Prepare the prepared statement
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    echo 'SQL statement failed';
                } else {
                    //Bind parameters to the placeholder
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $category);
                    //Run parameters inside database
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                    if ($resultCheck < 1) {

                        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=nocategories
         exit();'>";
                    } else {
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                        echo $row['points'];
                        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM rewards WHERE reward_points >= ?;";

                        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        //Prepare the prepared statement
                        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
                            echo 'SQL statement failed';
                        } else {
                            //Bind parameters to the placeholder
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $row['points']);
                            //Run parameters inside database
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                            $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                            $resultCheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

                            if ($resultCheck2 < 1) {

                                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=lackofpoints'>";
                                exit();
                            } else {
                                $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE subscriptionplan3 IS NULL;";

                                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                                //Prepare the prepared statement
                                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
                                    echo 'SQL statement failed';
                                } else {
                                    //Bind parameters to the placeholder

                                    //Run parameters inside database
                                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                    $result3 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                                    $resultCheck3 = mysqli_num_rows($result3);

                                    echo $resultCheck3;

                                    if ($resultCheck3 < 1) {
                                        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=noqualifiedlevel3users'>";
                                        exit();
                                    } else {
                                        echo '<table class="admin_level3promo">

           <tr>
           <th colspan="2" class="update_title">Welcome to the Administrator\'s Level 3 Promo Qualified Users\' Section</th>
           </tr>';

                                        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                                            while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {

                                                echo '<tr>
                      <th>Result No:</th><td>', htmlspecialchars($rowCounter), '</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>ID:</th><td>', htmlspecialchars($row2['id']), '</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Username:</th><td>', htmlspecialchars($row2['user_uid']), '</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>E-Mail:</th><td>', htmlspecialchars($row2['user_email']), '</td>
                      </tr>';


                                            }

                                            echo '</table>';


                                            $rowCounter = 0;


                                            $rowCounter++;


                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkh8S.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Knz.png

As can be seen, only musician888 should qualify because she has more than 5000 points but I am getting number 10 returned when echoing $resultCheck3
````

Comment: Since this is a DB design related question, please show us your table schemas/designs for the relevant tables. You can remove the PHP code from the question too.

Comment: Is there a problem with using too many while loops? I guess I should only have one while loop at the very end

Comment: I wouldn't worry about those 2 while loops. They seem OK since you're not executing queries within them. However, this code seems overly complicated for simply outputting a table with results from a query. Perhaps you could edit your question with your table designs for _rewards_, _memberships_, and _level3promo_. We might be able to help you out with a suggestion or two.